# Skeletal tracker for Asus Xtion Pro Live

Tags: ros, skeleton-tracker, skeletal-tracker, asus-xtion-pro-live

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm new to the forum and I've a problem with skeletal tracking by using Asus Xtion Pro Live. I've installed openni2_camera and openni2_launch and the system fuction correctly. So I can use Xtion Pro Live with ros, and I can create a pointclouder in rviz and other tools. I've tried to use openni_tracker to tracking the skeleton but this node does not function with Xtion Pro Live. Does anyone has the same problem? Does anyone known if there is an alternative node can I use to track the skeleton with Xtion Pro Live? Thank you for your attention!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195459/skeletal-tracker-for-asus-xtion-pro-live/) by [carloharris](https://answers.ros.org/users/20534/carloharris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This morning I solved my problem. Below I explain what I've done.

1. From this source I installed the openni2_tracker from this link: https://github.com/futureneer/openni2-tracker
2. Then I downloaded NiTE-2.0.0 from this link http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/
   Since this link has died I used web archive to open the site
3. I downoloaded OpenNI2. I don't remember the way, but could be from this link https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2
4. At this point I modified the CMakeLists.txt in the openni2_tracker package (I've this package on my sandbox in the groovy_workspace). The change I made, indicates the path relative at the folder that contain the two folders  NiTE-2.0.0 and OpenNI2. This should be done because openni2_tracker use NiTE-2.0.0 and OpenNI2 to work. Compile the package to apply the change.
5. Since the command

> rosrun openni2_tracker openni2_tracker

doesn't work I tried to use

> roslaunch openni2_tracker tracker.launch

In this way I've seen that that the system need of the NiTE2 data, so I created a link of the folder NiTE2 (this folder is the NiTE-2.0.0 folder in the path Redist) in the .ros folder (.ros folder it's a hidden folder in the home). I run the command

> roslaunch openni2_tracker tracker.launch

The tracker work and with rviz I can see the skeleton tracking. I haven't yet try if openni2_tracker work with openni2_lunch. When I try I update the answer.
Scuse me if I writed some inaccuracies but I'm a rookie. Thank you for your attention.

---

Originally posted by [carloharris](https://answers.ros.org/users/20534/carloharris/) with karma: 36 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2014-10-23**:
I am not able to able to use openni2_launch and openni2_tracker at the same time. Please, let me know if you have success with it.

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-08-20**:
Hi, I'm trying to use

roslaunch openni2_tracker tracker.launch

But it gives me the next error
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [openni2_tracker/tracker]: can't locate node [tracker] in package [openni2_tracker]

Do you know what the problem is? im using ROS-Indigo on UBUNTU 14.04 and XTION

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-08-21**:
Finally i could solve this problem ;)

**Comment by [ishareef](https://answers.ros.org/users/22731/ishareef/) on 2015-08-27**:
@jaam002, so did you manage to solve it? If so, how? Because I'm stuck with the same problem, as well.

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-08-30**:
@ishareef yeah, the problem was i was using the openni2_tracker from futureneer and the CMake file of it was developed for "rosbuild" and not for "catkin". Nevertheless, the skeleton_tracker from Chaos works with catkin, so i used it.

https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2016-04-01**:
in step 4, you talk about modifying the openni2_tracker CMakeLists.txt file.
Which lines do you change?  It's not obvious to me...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I modified the original openni2_tracker node for publishing the video stream and the point cloud.
You can clone the package [here](https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker.git)
It is a catkinized version of the package, and it also publishes the IDs of the identified users.
I hope it is useful!

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/21755/skywalker/) on 2015-07-16**:
hi Chaos, thank you for your edits everything works fine except video stream. I get video stream but frequency is around 4 hz from /camera/rgb/image topic which is supposed to be around 30 hz. Do you get proper frequency ?

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2015-07-17**:
Hi @skywalker! That's strange... I can get the video-stream at 30 Hz... The topic's publish frequency is 15 Hz. Do you broadcast the video over a network? I mean: do you acquire the video with a PC and subscribe to it with another node on another PC?

**Comment by [drchopper](https://answers.ros.org/users/23563/drchopper/) on 2015-08-13**:
Hi,
the Note 2 Link doesn't work anymore. Do you have another link for me?
Thx

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2015-08-24**:
Hi @drChopper. Try [this](http://openni.ru/files/nite/) link. Otherwise, in the [cob_people_perception](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_people_perception) package you should find the nite2.

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-08-31**:
Hi, has somebody tested the skeleton tracker from @Chaos with the drivers from http://www.ros.org/news/2014/09/microsoft-kinect-v2-driver-released.html? i can't still figure out how to use it with the kinect v2

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2015-09-01**:
Sorry @jaam002, but the skeleton tracker I built is intended to be used with the ASUS Xtion Pro Live. I don't know if it can be also used with the Kinect...

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-09-30**:
@Chaos, why aren't you using depth_image_proc or something like that to produce the point clouds and the 32Float depth image? Is there a problem with that? Otherwise depth_image_proc can increase your topic publishing rate to 30hz or so depending or your computer's power...less computations to do

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2016-10-03**:
@Pototo, this was just my first trial in writing a ROS node for getting both the skeleton tracked from the XTion, the image, the depth image and the point cloud. I didn't know about the depth_image_proc existence.